# How run pika consumer and publisher in two threads?

Tags: python, pika

I use library pika 1.3.2 and threading.
I want run one connection with two channels: to consumer and to publisher.
I run two threads, and all Ok.

But how can I stop consumer and close channels and connection?

If I run `channel.stop_consuming(tag)`, `channel.close()` I get error: `AssertionError: ('_AsyncTransportBase._initate_abort() expected non-_STATE_COMPLETED', 4)`

```
import time

import pika
import threading

url = 'amqp://user:user@localhosh:5672/'


def run_consumer(connection, tag):

    def on_message(self, channel, method, properties, body):
        print(body)

    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare('queue', auto_delete=True)
    channel.basic_consume(
        queue='queue',
        auto_ack=False,
        on_message_callback=on_message,
        consumer_tag=tag
    )


def run_publisher(connection):
    channel = connection.channel()
    time.sleep(20)
    channel.basic_publish(
        exchange='',
        routing_key='queue',
        body='Test messange',
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parameters = pika.URLParameters(url)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    consumer_tag = 'consumer'
    thread_consumer = threading.Thread(
        target=run_consumer,
        args=(connection, consumer_tag),
        name='Consumer'
    )
    thread_consumer.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    thread_publisher = threading.Thread(
        target=run_publisher,
        args=(connection,),
        name='Publisher'
    )
    thread_publisher.start()
```

Comment: Your code is only working because you are lucky. Pika is not thread-safe. You should use a connection in each of your threads. If you need assistance, share your code via a git repository that I can clone and open a pull request against. GitHub or GitLab are ideal for this.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found a solution using ```add_callback_threadsafe```